# how .net 1.1 application can work with .net 2.0 assembly

Tags: .net-1.1

We have old .net 1.1 project that is using a third party component. Aparently that component is not working properly with new requirements, and there is no support from the provider. Provider proposed to use new component that is working properly. The problem is that this component requires .net 2.0.

The project is big and it will be costly to move this project to 2.0.

What other alternatives we can have? How 1.1 assembly can call 2.0 assembly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.NET 1.1 can't load .NET 2.0 assemblies, because the internal format changed. Your app will basically think that the assembly isn't a .NET assembly.

Long term, it would be a good idea to update your application to use .NET 2.0 (if not something newer, since there are multiple versions of .NET since 2.0 now). However, if that is not an option, you could create a .config file for your executable, and tell the CLR to always use .NET 2.0 when running your app. This should allow for the .NET 2.0 assembly to load, however any breaking changes between .NET 1.1 and 2.0 that your app makes use of will cause errors.

Comment: Do you think that creating wrapper object around 2.0 assembly with required functionality and expose it as COM dll as a good idea?

Comment: @user976536 I don't think that would work. Before .NET 4.0, a process can only have 1 CLR running in it. If you try to load the COM object from your .NET 1.1 app, it must load .NET 2.0 in order to load the .NET 2.0 assembly. This will give you an error, since the .NET 1.1 CLR is already loaded into the process.